# "Biur Sheimot Kodesh ve-Chol leha-Rambam" Authentic?

Tags: jewish-books, rambam, authorship

I just came across a work called ביאור שמות קדש וחול which is attributed to the Rambam--see, e.g., [here](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pagefeed/hebrewbooks_org_51465_20.pdf). Is this an authentic work of the Rambam? What is known about it?  I found the work on hebrewbooks.org [here](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=31484&pgnum=1).

Comment: Do you have any reason to think it isn't?

Comment: @Danno yes, I never heard of it,  it apparently wasn't published until relatively recently, and there are many works falsely attributed to the Rambam

Answer (score 6):

I found an article by Yaakov Levinger (על הספר 'ביאור שמות קדש וחול' המיוחס לרמב"ם, מחקרי ירושלים במחשבת ישראל ד) which addresses this sefer. He notes that Prof. Saul Lieberman, R. Menachem Mendel Kasher, and others considered the work to be authentic, however, he considers it to clearly be a forgery. His proofs are:

1. in this work, the "Rambam" identifies God with His name, a doctrine which does not match the Rambam's position but instead those of the early kabbalists.
2. This work refers to the appearance of *ruach ha-kodesh* in *beit midrasho shel Ever*, which would be a foreign concept for the Rambam for whom *ruach ha-kodesh* appears only to individuals, not institutions. [This seems to be a weak proof, as this may be a mere figure of speech.]
3. This work refers to the midrash which says that "a maidservant saw at the splittings of the sea what Ezekiel did not see," a statement which the Rambam himself never quotes, as it seems to go against his philosophy. [Skipping a few proofs.]
4. Until this work was published by Moses Gaster in 1923, no one ever heard of it--including R. Avraham ben ha-Rambam who never mentions it in his commentary on the Torah or anywhere else, even where he had opportunities to do so.
5. The language does not match the Rambam's Hebrew writings. [This seems like a strong argument to me.]
6. The work shows the influence of the Ramba*n*, even containing a close paraphrase of an entire comment of the Ramba*n*. [This would seem to be incontrovertible evidence.]

(It should be noted that in the [new edition](https://pbs.twimg.com/media/C_AQPODVoAAy3gp.jpg) of the Frankel Rambam, this work will be included at the end of the Ahavah volume.)
See also note 4 here [https://orot.ac.il/בענין-איסור-מחיקת-שמות-ה-עיון-מקיף-לגבי-השם-בית-אל#_ftn4](https://orot.ac.il/%D7%91%D7%A2%D7%A0%D7%99%D7%9F-%D7%90%D7%99%D7%A1%D7%95%D7%A8-%D7%9E%D7%97%D7%99%D7%A7%D7%AA-%D7%A9%D7%9E%D7%95%D7%AA-%D7%94-%D7%A2%D7%99%D7%95%D7%9F-%D7%9E%D7%A7%D7%99%D7%A3-%D7%9C%D7%92%D7%91%D7%99-%D7%94%D7%A9%D7%9D-%D7%91%D7%99%D7%AA-%D7%90%D7%9C#_ftn4) :

> חיבור קצר זה נדפס לראשונה בשנת התרפ"ג תחת השם "ביאור שמות קודש וחול",
> ומטרתו היתה לבאר אילו מן השמות בתורה הינם קודש וצריך הסופר לקדשם, ואילו
> מן השמות אינם קודש ואין לקדשם, ולשם כך נעזר הרמב"ם פעמים רבות בתרגום
> אונקלוס. בשנת התשמ"ז ההדירו מחדש הגאון הרב יצחק רצאבי שליט"א וקראו
> ''שמות קודש וחול'' עם פירושו הקרוי נזר הקודש. במבואו האריך הרב רצאבי
> שליט"א שאין לנו שום סיבה לפקפק בייחוסו האמיתי של החיבור לרמב"ם, ואכן
> ראיתי בכמה מקומות שחכמי ישראל ייחסוהו לרמב"ם ללא עוררין. עיין לדוגמא
> דברי הרב מנחם כשר בספרו תורה שלמה (כרך לה עמ' יד). אולם לא אכחד שהרה"ג
> אשר וייס שליט"א כתב לי בזו הלשון: "ומה שהבאת מדברי הרמב"ם בספר "שמות
> קודש וחול" דשם בית אל קודש הוא, ספר זה למיטב ידיעתי לאו גושפנקא דמר בר
> רב אשי חתום עליה, וספק גדול מי חיברו. אינני חוקר ואין בידי לברר שורש
> הדברים, אך אין לדחות דברי הא"ר והחת"ס עמודי ההלכה מספר שאין לו מסורת
> ברורה".

Comment: Very interesting. How did those proofs (especially 3, 5 and 6) get past Rav Kasher?